# how to use webhooks in javascript?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, axios, webhooks, vuejs3

so I am having a bit of trouble understanding webhooks.

I am working with Vue.js and Axios and am trying to see if there's a way to store data in a firebase database when a webhook changes (i am using picqer webhooks) but I cannot figure out how to do this as looking at a webhook looks like more of a serverside (possibly php?)thing.

is there someone out there that could teach me how to either make a script that looks at the webhook and if it changes 24/7

or explain how they work in php and how I can easily store that data in a firebase database

Comment: This is irrelevant to client-side JS. This needs to be processed in server app (php or node or anything) or possibly could be solved with FB alone. Try to explore 'firebase function webook'.

Comment: will look into this, didn't know firebase had a built-in thing to potentially handle this